# Merge meshes in edit mode

Tags: mesh

beginner here. Is there any way to merge overlapping meshes? See both of the images provided. What I made is just one object, but a terrible amount of vertexes crossing over.

[image: Object]

[image: Mesh]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Remesh modifier. It may be slow to operate and be worth applying, but that will merge and remove any internal geometry you might have.

Answer (score 0):

I beleve that your mesh is to messy for my and even regular workflor.

But try to you Mesh Boolean Geometry node with only one input.

[image]
[image]

Then you need it to Convert to mesh.
But in result you'll get even more vertices amout.

Comment: Yeah I reckoned that. I've made this shape with geometry nodes. Therefore I hoped to get an more even shape, since all of the egdes are crossing over. Is there a better way than what I proposed?